# Case when versus if else statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-performance

Can someone explain if there is any performance difference between "case when" and "if-else" in SQL Server? And in which scenario should I use which statement?

```
IF DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE()) IN (N'Saturday', N'Sunday')
       SELECT 'Weekend';
ELSE 
       SELECT 'Weekday';
   

select
case when DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE()) IN (N'Saturday', N'Sunday') 
        then 'Weekend'
    else 
             'Weekday'
 end
```

Comment: Firstly case is an expression - not a statement, secondly their use-case is completely different, one modifies the result of a query, one modifies the flow path of executing statements. In SQL you should avoid procedural logic if possible as its optimised for set based operations e.g. queries.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can only use the first version from a stored procedure.  For a regular query, you'll have to use the second version.

Comment: Or you can use [`iif()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), which is a bit neater in simple cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested both queries in `Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)`  . There is no performance difference between them, except that SELECT CASE is little ahead in milliseconds.

```sql
SELECT GETUTCDATE()
GO
--IF DATENAME(SECOND, GETDATE()) IN (N'Saturday', N'Sunday')
--       SELECT 'Weekend';
--ELSE 
--       SELECT 'Weekday';
select
case when DATENAME(SECOND, GETDATE()) IN (N'Saturday', N'Sunday') 
        then 'Weekend'
    else 
    'Weekday'
 end
GO 50
SELECT GETUTCDATE()
GO
```

> For IF ELSE logic:
>
> SELECT DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, '2020-07-09 04:40:21.170','2020-07-09
> 04:40:27.693')
>
> --6523 milliseconds
>
> For CASE logic:
> SELECT DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, '2020-07-09
> 04:41:35.580','2020-07-09 04:41:41.973')
>
> --6393 milliseconds

But, as @Dale K, mentioned, they are generally having different use cases. SELECT helps in setting multiple variable values at a single time. If Else logic, you have to set values separately. If else logic, can have lots of business logic internally. SELECT CASE is a single statment.

Comment: And of course comparing such a simple case isn't really a good indication anyway. You've have to compare using a complex example. If the case expression was very complex then using `if` could potentially be much faster assuming its possible to split into multiple simple queries.

Comment: @DaleK, yes. agree with you. It is case to case basis. In this particular case, I found `SELECT CASE` to be little bit faster, compare to `IF ELSE` logic.

Answer (score -1):

The case statement will work properly for a performance basis. Because CASE statement we can directly use in any select query without specifying Transact-SQL syntax, but if you are going to use IF statement in which it will work as Transact-SQL query syntax(as you have used SELECT statement twice), but in case you have to use it once only.

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** - ***NOT*** a statement .....

Comment: My bad, I know it just not able to frame it properly. Thanks to correcting me.